# Spring Angular OAuth

Tags: spring, angular, oauth

I work with Angular 5 and Spring Boot.

My angular client needs financial information placed on a third-party banking server.
All of this financial data is available from a REST API with OAuth authentication.

I would not want my angular client to directly request the bank server;
I prefer my spring server to request the bank server and return the results to my angular client.

As an Oauth authentication for the bank server is required, what is the correct workflow between these three parties?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to register yourself with the bank server
2. get the token from the bankserver after successfull client registration
3. use the token to call the actual api you want to call
4. change the result to your custom model if required
5. return from the @RestController method

Step 2 depends on the bank server. how they have exposed the api for you to register and get token

Comment: Thanks a lot Ravi